# Computing order statistics $1,2,4,8,\ldots,n$

Tags: algorithms, time-complexity

> On an array of $n = 2^k$ numbers, where $k$ is a non-negative integer, the $k = \log n$ order statistics $1, 2, 4, 8,\ldots, 2^k$ can all be determined in a total of $Θ(n)$ time in the worst case.

I think that this statement is wrong because the loop will take $k$ iterations. So, the time should be $Θ(\log(n))$. But, I'm not sure my guess is correct. Could you tell me whether or not my guess is correct?

Answer (score 1):

You can find all of these order statistics in $O(n)$. First, find the maximum (order statistic $2^k$) in time $O(n)$. Then, find the median (order statistic $2^{k-1}$) in time $O(n)$, and remove all larger elements. Find order statistic $2^{k-2}$ in time $O(n/2)$, and remove all larger elements. And so on. The total running time is $$O(n + n/2 + n/4 + \cdots) = O(n).$$